# NM-B Romex going through conduit raceway to external breaker box. Not code compliant?

Tags: electrical

I recently noticed one connection in my breaker box where 12/2 Romex exits the house in a conduit and enters the breaker box.  The breaker box is on the external wall of the house. I thought this was considered a wet location and therefore running Romex through conduit is prohibited.

Just wanted to make sure that this violates code.  I am going to have to rewire this before I have the inspector come in for another job I am doing right now.

Here is a picture of the breaker box - Look for yellow cable popping out from bottom right corner.
[image]

Picture of conduit attached to the breaker box
[image]

[Picture of the electrical box where conduit terminates (both inside and outside of the box)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CX5EY.jpg)

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you provide us with a photo that shows the conduit entering the box?

Comment: Don't have exactly what you asked, but I posted a second picture that is pretty close to what you are asking.

Comment: Is there a junction box at the other end of this conduit, or does it just dump the NM out into a wall...?

Comment: The fact that the circuit’s neutral and ground wires land on the same screw is definitely a code violation. Can’t do that.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel The cable goes to an electrical box that contains an outlet.  It's inside the fireplace for a electrical heater.

Comment: @cryptic0 -- does the *conduit* go all the way to that box though?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel : I have no way of telling.  It's a brick veneer wall on both sides.  I see conduit connected to the wall and on the other side there is an electrical outlet box.

Comment: @cryptic0 -- can you post photos of the inside of the outlet box then please?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel: Will do.  What if the conduit is connected to the box?  Is that code? What about romex running in wet locations?

Comment: @cryptic0 -- the conduit being connected to the box makes solving this easier, at least

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel: Added a pic.

Comment: @cryptic0 -- can you get us a photo of the inside of the outlet box itself? (i.e. turn the breaker off, unfasten the receptacle and cover but don't unwire it, and shoot us a photo of the interior of that receptacle box)

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel: Can you explain what you are expecting to see inside? As far as I can tell, if the conduit is connected to the box, then that romex is directly attached to the receptacle terminals.  Are you expecting that something funky is going on inside?

Comment: @cryptic0 -- what I want to see is where the conduit enters the box, that'll tell me if the conduit truly enters the box, allowing us to simply replace the wires inside the conduit with The Right Thing, or if something goofy's going on instead

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel Finally had a chance to take these pics.  See the last link in my original question.

Comment: I take it you can't get the cover off the box without messing up the wiring @cryptic0?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel No I posted pictures of inside the box too.  Check the imgur link.

Comment: Based on the paper, there's also a bunch of NM/B in the larger back-entry conduit.

Answer (score 3):

If the conduit continues into a box for the receptacle just replace with thhn. If the conduit is just a sleeve to protect the romex it would need to be changes to type uf-b  because the conduit would be considered a wet location

Comment: From the pictures posted, it doesn't look like the conduit is connected to the junction box so it's probably a sleeve.+1